# Unable to view the Text View Dropped in Design view of android studio

Tags: android

I have recentely started learning `android studio` and I know nothing about the errors.

I am dropping the text and buttons to the design view but I am unable to see them.
[[image]]

Here are a few errors that are apperaring at the top right corner.
[[image]]

The errors say:

1. Failed to find style `coordinatorLayoutStyle` in current theme.
2. This view is not constrained. It only has designtime positions, so it will jump to `(0,0)` at runtime unless you add the constraints.
3. Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?

Some fixes that i have tried after googling are:

In `styles.xml` changing

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

[[image]]

Also i found that i should change:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

But in place of `alpha3` there is `rc01`

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
```

[[image]]

Nothing worked for me, please need a detailed answer as I am new to android studio.

Comment: Please be more clear in posting the question, as well as  having the "enter image description here" telling actual image meaning..

Answer (score 0):

remove this from gradel

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0- alpha3
```

and add this

```
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompatv7:27.0.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'

 like this


 android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "e.lenovo.alldemo"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Comment: I did and its showing this error "This support library should not use a different vrsion(27)  Than the compileSdkVersion(28)'"

Comment: change your compileSdkVersion version 28 to 27 and target version also 27

Comment: How can i do this ?